# Consider setting CROSS_F77_SIZEOF_INTEGER to the length in bytes of a Fortran INTEGER

Tags: integer, mpich

While compiling mpich 3.2 with gcc-6.3, I get this error:

> configure: error: Unable to configure with Fortran support because
>   configure could not determine the size of a Fortran INTEGER.  Consider
>   setting CROSS_F77_SIZEOF_INTEGER to the length in bytes of a Fortran
>   INTEGER

Where do I set CROSS_F77_SIZEOF_INTEGER to get rid of the error?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Where do I set CROSS_F77_SIZEOF_INTEGER? and get rid of the error

Comment: The information here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356554/install-mpich-on-centos-error-could-not-determine-the-size-of-a-fortran-integer/356555) might solve your problem. The information there is useful and solve the issue if you don't need mpich with fortran.